# "Повидимому" или "по-видимому"?

Tags: грамматика, вводные-слова

В литературе встречал оба варианта, хотя первый вариант обычно встречается в старых книгах. Какова современная норма? Не путать с "по видимому (берегу...)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Слово "по-видимому" с дефисным написанием упоминается в Правилах 1956 года и приведено в прилагаемом к  правилам словаре.

Информация в статье [Орфография русского языка до 1956 года | wikipedia.org](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE_1956_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Старый вариант: Повидимому, попрежнему, попустому. Ныне — по-видимому, по-прежнему, по-пустому.